# Error: A method named 'MeteorToys' is already defined

Tags: meteor

I have a project that work just fine with meteor v.1.8.3, I need to use some functions of mongodb v.3.6, so I need to update my project to meteor 1.11 in order to use mongodb 3.6, the problem is when I update to meteor 1.11 and run the project that error is shown to me, I tried to update the project to all the 1.9 and 1.10 sub-versions and everything works good, however doesn't work with meteor 1.11 or superior versions which is what I need, here is the complete log:

```
/home/s/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.11.0.c9w1gh.d443p++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
throw(ex);
^

Error: A method named 'MeteorToys' is already defined
at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1595:15
at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:147:22)
at Server.methods (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1591:7)
at packages/meteortoys_shell.js:27:956
at packages/meteortoys_shell.js:30:4
at packages/meteortoys_shell.js:34:4
at packages/meteortoys_shell.js:40:3
at /home/s/jg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:401:38
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at /home/s/jg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:226:21
at /home/s/jg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:464:7
at Function.run (/home/s/jg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:280:14)
at /home/s/jg/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:13
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Help please

Comment: Looks like an issue with that package. Have you checked that they support release 1.11? Also, how did you update, using `meteor update` or using `meteor update --release`?

Comment: I don't even use that package, it's installed in the update process which is made with the --release flag @ChristianFritz

Comment: they why not just remove it?

Comment: To be honest I was afraid to broke meteor since the package is installed automatically, but reading meteortoys docs I found that is just development package, so I'm going to try that, thanks  @christianfritz

Comment: meteortoys is definitely not installed automatically, as part of an update or otherwise. If you are not using it, you should uninstall it

Comment: uninstall the package worked for me, thank you both so much @ChristianFritz